# Shopware 6 Custom plugin that changes the schedule task interval value

Tags: shopware, shopware6

I want to create a plugin that can set the scheduled task interval. Shopware has database field called run_interval in Schedule_task table. The admin will enter a value, this value will change the run_interval in the scheduled_task table. Is this possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to [use a plugin configuration](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/add-plugin-configuration) for the input field. You could then set up a subscriber to listen for changes of the config field and update the scheduled task entity.

Service definition:

```xml
<service id="Foo\MyPlugin\Subscriber\SystemConfigChangedSubscriber">
    <argument type="service" id="scheduled_task.repository"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

Subscriber:

```php
class SystemConfigChangedSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private EntityRepositoryInterface $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityRepositoryInterface $repository)
    {
        $this->repository = $repository;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            SystemConfigChangedEvent::class => 'onSystemConfigChanged',
        ];
    }

    public function onSystemConfigChanged(SystemConfigChangedEvent $event): void
    {
        if ($event->getKey() !== 'MyPluginName.config.nameOfMyField') {
            return;
        }

        $context = Context::createDefaultContext();
        $criteria = new Criteria();
        $criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('name', 'name_of_the.task'));
        $taskId = $this->repository->searchIds($criteria, $context)->firstId();

        if (!$taskId) {
            return;
        }

        $this->repository->update([
            [
                'id' => $taskId,
                'runInterval' => $event->getValue(),
            ],
        ], $context);
    }
}
```

Comment: I followed all the steps, it worked. Thanks a lot!